# WordPress plugin - Contact Form 7 - Cannot get the submit button line up. Won't center

Tags: forms, contacts

I have a brand new WordPress theme that I've created. I installed Contact Form 7 and I'm trying to center the contact form and the submit button.

[image: Contact Form 7 alignment issue]

The submit/send button has a strange margin on the right hand side. I'm not sure why. I've checked the css code and I don't see why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following css code to my style.css file.

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

This issue is now resolved.